# An Inbuilt function to find Difference Between Two Images for Android (Kotlin Preferred)

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app, I want to find the difference between two Images, almost similar but with a slight difference. The function should extract the difference and should give out an image that contains the difference it extracted. Input should be two images. (I saw another related question in StackOverflow but it was posted 8 years ago, and the solution was brute force approached) Please suggest a few functions (inbuilt functions preferred) in Kotlin, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a "brute force approach" in this context, and what would it take for it to _not_ be a brute force solution?

Comment: comparing every pixel! it will take forever for sure ! XD Some thing like this

bool imagesAreEqual(Image i1, Image i2)
{
    if (i1.getHeight() != i2.getHeight()) return false;
    if (i1.getWidth() != i2.getWidth()) return false;

    for (int y = 0; y < i1.getHeight(); ++y)
       for (int x = 0; x < i1.getWidth(); ++x)
            if (i1.getPixel(x, y) != i2.getPixel(x, y)) return false;

    return true;
}

Comment: It will be `O(nm)` complexity, but as long as the images aren't ginormous, it won't take too long. Though how do you expect to find _all_ differences without looking at every pixel? Granted, I'm not computer vision (or whatever field) expert, but I would suspect any "smart" approach (e.g., edge/feature detection) would simply add complexity on top of looking at every pixel.

Comment: I really appreciate your input, But I am leaning more towards the accuracy rather than the time complexity. As far as I know, Inbuilt functions tend to have both, so I'd really appreciate it if you can suggest me some.

Comment: There's no built-in function for this, it's a very specialised task you'll need to find a library for, or identify your own requirements and write/find an algorithm that covers them. The concept of "difference" between two images is extremely broad and complex, especially if you're talking about identifying differences a human would perceive (which I assume you are since you want to represent that "difference" in the form of another image for a human to look at). Comparing the pixel bytes of two images is easy enough, drawing any meaning from that is the hard / extremely broad part

Comment: Maybe look into OpenCV or something - but again, it really depends on what you're actually trying to *do*. A lot of this stuff really isn't trivial, and if you're asking here, you've honestly probably got a lot of studying ahead of you, it's pretty specialist (I barely know anything about it either!). If you can find a suitable image comparison library, where someone's already done the work / trained the model etc and you can just drop it in and use it, that would be best. I don't know any, but that's what I'd probably focus on looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, but its not pefect... I'm still trying to improve this or trying to find other solutions.

```
 import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback
 import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface
 import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader
 import org.opencv.android.Utils
 import org.opencv.core.Core

 private fun extractDifference(before :Bitmap, after:Bitmap):Bitmap{

   val beforemat = Mat()
   Utils.bitmapToMat(before, beforemat)
   val aftermat = Mat()
   Utils.bitmapToMat(after, aftermat)
   val diff= Mat()
   Core.absdiff(beforemat, aftermat, diff)
   Utils.matToBitmap(diff,before)
   return before
   }
```